# Linked Service from azure Data factory to Databricks: How to parametrize?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am using new job cluster option while creating linked service from ADF (Data factory) to Databricks with spark configs. I want to parametrize the spark config values as well as keys. I know it's quite easy to parametrize values by referring [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters). But is it possible to parametrize spark config keys also, I highlighted them with red?

[image: Linked_service_adf_to_databricks]

If there is any other way like databricks cluster init scripts to achieve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When writing an ARM template for Data Factory, which , like per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/linkedservices?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#resource-format) you can include a "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"  resource, and in there you can define eventually, the `newClusterSparkConf`, briefly like below, but there are more details in that  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/linkedservices?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#resource-format).

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "variables": {},
  "parameters": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "blah",
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
      "properties": {
        "parameters": {},
        "type": "AzureDatabricks",
        "typeProperties": {
          "accessToken": {
              "type": 'string'
          }
          "newClusterNodeType": "a node type",
          "newClusterNumOfWorker": "2",
          "newClusterSparkConf": {
            "key": "value",
            "abcd": "efgh",
            "pars": "tuvw",
          },
          "newClusterVersion": "a version",
          "newClusterSparkEnvVars": {
            "somevar": "one",
            "anothervar": "two",
          }
        }
      },

    }
  ]
}
```